# Simple Select returning null instead of value

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

and what I need is a sum of amounts in given year for given department.

I tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `spendings` WHERE dept_name='fiz' AND YEAR(date)=2012
```

but it only returns `NULL`. `dept_name` is a `varchar`, `amount` is a `double` and `date` - well, it's a `date`, what a surprise.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to your data, there are no rows for department "fiz" for the year 2012, so there's no amount to sum up.

Comment: OMG I haven't yet made such a silly mistake! And I'm thinking how to solve it for half an hour already.. damn! But it's 2.15 AM in Poland so.. maybe it's time for some sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any records `WHERE dept_name='fiz' AND YEAR(date)=2012`. The two records for dept `'fiz'` are for `'2010'` and `'2011'`.

Answer (score 0):

Department fiz doesn't have any records on year 2012 therefore the sum of no queries found is Null

Answer (score 0):

If that table is actually the data that you are querying, there are no records for the year 2012 (only 2010 and 2011)

Answer (score 0):

just to not repeat other anwsers, if you expect a cero, then use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM `spendings` WHERE dept_name='fiz' AND YEAR(date)=2012
```

please observe `COALESCE` function here